# Schedule multiple events under 1 timestamp

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to schedule multiple events or TODOs under one timestamp? If it is not possible what would be a reasonable alternative to what I am trying to do?

Basically I like to schedule my days at once listing everything that needs to be done or was done.

It might look something like this:

```
* Agenda
** Week 30
*** School Day <2017-07-24>
**** TODO math
**** TODO science
```

I also want every entry to show up in my agenda.